# Phrase used for daily status meeting?

Tags: adjetivos, sustantivos

What phrase is used in Latin America for a daily status meeting among coworkers or team members in a business setting?

Comment: I can think of _«reunión diaria de seguimiento»_ (or just _«reunión diaria»_ or _«reunión de seguimiento»_ if the context is clear).

Comment: Then would reunión be more appropriate in this setting then la junta?

Comment: @DavidSopko Yes, _"junta"_ is more used for decisions makers meetings ("junta directiva", "junta de accionistas", "junta de gobierno", etc.)

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón Your comment seems to have general acceptance. Why don't you promote it into an answer? :-)

Comment: Carlos's answer is correct. In addition if the meeting were while you are setting up a business it would be *montar un negocio* or *iniciar un negocio*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer seems to be *«reunión diaria de seguimiento»*.

*«Seguimiento»* translates as “follow-up”, “monitoring” or “tracking”, while a more literal translation to “status” would be *«estado»*, but I think *«seguimiento»* is more appropriate than *«estado»* for this context.  Otherwise it is a litteral translation of “daily status meeting.”

If context is clear then it can be shortened to *«reunión diaria»* or *«reunión de seguimiento»*.